# Remove string from byte image

Tags: c#, arrays, image, sockets, byte

could you help me with that one? I'm using Vs2019 , .net core 3.1

My socket is receiving an image and I need to remove some string from the byte[] received.

e.g. Socket receive Image1,Size,ID,XXXXX  (where XXXXX is the image)

I need to remove the start of the string (Image1,Size,ID,) to be able to save the image in the disk. If I decode the string and use the string.replace("Image1,Size,ID,",""), it will break my image and I won't be able to generate the image.

More example:

```
            byte[] newFile = File.ReadAllBytes("C:\\test.txt"); //Socket is saving data in this file
            
            string strFile = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(newFile);
            strFile.Replace("Image1,Size,ID,", "");

            byte[] newArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(strFile);

            using (FileStream fsNew = new FileStream("C:\\image.jpg", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
            {
                fsNew.Write(newArray, 0, newArray.Length); //Corrupted File is generated. 
            }
```

Thanks

Comment: OK; how is the string and image data separated in the binary? meaning: it sounds like you've got a mix of text and image data: where does one end?

Answer (score 1):

You should not treat binary data as text, and certainly not as 7bit ASCII text. That will corrupt the data, as you discovered.

There is no need to involve `System.Text.Encoding` at all in this situation. You know how many bytes you want to skip, so just skip them. `Write()` lets you pass in a starting offset to copy from, eg

```cs
byte[] newFile = File.ReadAllBytes("C:\\test.txt"); //Socket is saving data in this file

using (FileStream fsNew = new FileStream("C:\\image.jpg", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
{
    fsNew.Write(newFile, 15, newFile.Length-15);
}
```

If, for some reason, you did need to treat binary data as text and then back to binary, then at least [use codepage 437 to avoid corruption](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20200831-00/?p=104142).

```cs
byte[] newFile = File.ReadAllBytes("C:\\test.txt"); //Socket is saving data in this file

Encoding enc = Encoding.GetEncoding(437);

string strFile = enc.GetString(newFile);
strFile = strFile.Remove(0, 15);
byte[] newArray = enc.GetBytes(strFile);

using (FileStream fsNew = new FileStream("C:\\image.jpg", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
{
    fsNew.Write(newArray, 0, newArray.Length);
}
```

Comment: Thank you Remy, I ended up skipping some positions in my array as you suggested. :)